# Dual booting ubuntu 14.04-windows 10 on separate ssd and efi partition

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, multi-boot, grub

I have a **laptop** with two ssd and one hdd (hdd is for storage,not os) and I have windows 10 installed on one ssd and I want to install ubuntu on other ssd. However I can not disconnect drives during the process as recommended on online guides because m.2 ssd's are under the motherboard and hard to reach.

Now for the background. I previously had one ssd and dual-booted with separate partitions. I deleted ubuntu but could not delete grub. Now that I have another brand new ssd and I fresh installed windows 10 on it and deleted the Windows from other ssd using disk management like I used for ubuntu. Note that I still have grub(I can only exit from grub by typing exit at booting and reach my Windows).
 My partitions look like this:

```
Disk 0: Old ssd, gonna use for ubuntu.
Disk 1: New ssd, windows installed.
Disk 2: HDD
```

Partitions:

[image: Partitions]

Now for my questions:

1. Should I move efi partitions(and maybe recoveries) to the new ssd before installing ubuntu?
2. Can I install ubuntu without disconnecting drives during process?
3. I guess I am going to install grub again. Could there be any problem if I overwrite current grub?